# Windows batch file: For loop each file obtained via DIR command

Tags: batch-file

I have the following bat file:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET @logPath=C:\Users\rialves\Documents\Teste\
SET @date=2015-04-07
@ECHO ON
FOR /f %%f IN ('DIR /s /b %@logPath% ^| findstr %@date% ^| findstr .zip') DO ECHO %%f
PAUSE
```

If I run the command `DIR /s /b %@logPath% | findstr %@date% | findstr .zip`
I get the following output:

```
C:\Users\rialves\Documents\Teste\REST.API\rest api 1\2015-04-07.zip
C:\Users\rialves\Documents\Teste\REST.API\rest api 1\teste 2015-04-07 - Copy.zip
C:\Users\rialves\Documents\Teste\REST.API\rest api 1 - Copy\2015-04-07.zip
C:\Users\rialves\Documents\Teste\REST.API\rest api 1 - Copy (2)\2015-04-07.zip
C:\Users\rialves\Documents\Teste\REST.API\rest api 1 - Copy (3)\2015-04-07.zip
C:\Users\rialves\Documents\Teste\REST.API\rest api 1 - Copy (4)\2015-04-07.zip
C:\Users\rialves\Documents\Teste\REST.API\rest api 1 - Copy (5)\2015-04-07.zip
```

However, when echoing via FOR loop I get:

```
C:\Users\rialves\Documents\Teste>ECHO C:\Users\rialves\Documents\Teste\REST.API\rest
C:\Users\rialves\Documents\Teste\REST.API\rest

C:\Users\rialves\Documents\Teste>ECHO C:\Users\rialves\Documents\Teste\REST.API\rest
C:\Users\rialves\Documents\Teste\REST.API\rest

C:\Users\rialves\Documents\Teste>ECHO C:\Users\rialves\Documents\Teste\REST.API\rest
C:\Users\rialves\Documents\Teste\REST.API\rest

C:\Users\rialves\Documents\Teste>ECHO C:\Users\rialves\Documents\Teste\REST.API\rest
C:\Users\rialves\Documents\Teste\REST.API\rest

C:\Users\rialves\Documents\Teste>ECHO C:\Users\rialves\Documents\Teste\REST.API\rest
C:\Users\rialves\Documents\Teste\REST.API\rest

C:\Users\rialves\Documents\Teste>ECHO C:\Users\rialves\Documents\Teste\REST.API\rest
C:\Users\rialves\Documents\Teste\REST.API\rest

C:\Users\rialves\Documents\Teste>ECHO C:\Users\rialves\Documents\Teste\REST.API\rest
C:\Users\rialves\Documents\Teste\REST.API\rest
```

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try `FOR /f "delims=" %%f in …` or  `FOR /f "tokens=*" %%f in …`, read https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html

Comment: You need to select/request all `Tokens` or remove/choose no `Delimiters` because the default delimiters are on `whitespace`. Either `FOR /f "Tokens=*" %%f IN ('...` or `FOR /f "Delims=" %%f IN ('...`.

Comment: You could shorten the code to: `FOR /R "%@logPath%" %%f IN (*%@date%*.zip) DO ECHO %%f`

Answer (score 2):

Your output strings are truncated at the first space within the path because FOR /F defaults to parsing tokens delimited by spaces and/or tabs.

The solution is simple - disable the DELIMS option in your FOR /F so that the entire path is considered to be a single token.

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%f IN ...
```